# If $f$ is even and $f′(0)$ exists, what is $f′(0)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, even-and-odd-functions

This is a homework question, and I was wondering if anyone could critique my answer?

[image]

We know that the derivative of every even function is an odd function.

We also know that every odd function is rotationally symmetric about the point $(0,0)$. So the function $f'(x)$ must contain the point $(0,0)$, therefore $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: "We know that the derivative of every function is an odd function.", no, the derivative of every **even** function is odd, but this seems to be not using the hint

Comment: @CalvinKhor, Thank you i did mean that, i edited the post. 
And yes im a little worried that I cant figure out how to use the hint, and therefore might not get the points

Comment: "We know that the derivative of every even function is an odd function."  How do we know?

Comment: @AndrewChin well, i found the statement in the book, but aside from that c*x^(2n) for any integer n goes to 2n*c*x^(2n-1) and 2n-1 is odd?

Comment: @Wombles That only proves the result if $f$ is a monomial, not for a general differentiable function. For that matter, how do you know that $f$ *is* differentiable anywhere except at $x=0$?

Comment: bungo, good question, I suppose i don't

Comment: Since $f(x) = f(-x)$ then the chain rule gives $f'(x) = -f'(-x)$. What happens if you set $x=0$?

Comment: @copper.hat we have not been officially taught the chain rule yet, that was the first thing i wanted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution works.

If you want to use the hint then if you add the two expressions for the derivative then you get
$$2f'(x)=\lim \limits_{h \to o}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{h} $$
then let $x=0$ then we get.
$$2f'(0)=\lim \limits_{h \to o}\frac{f(h)-f(-h)}{h} $$
and as $f$ is even then $f(-x)=f(x)$, which impliees $f(-h)-f(h)=0$ therefore
$$2f'(0)=\lim \limits_{h \to o}\frac{f(h)-f(-h)}{h} =\lim \limits_{h \to o}\frac{0}{h}=0$$
therefore $f'(0)=0$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$(1) \quad f'(0)= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$

and

$(2) \quad f'(0)= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(-h)-f(0)}{h}$.

Now add $(1)$ and $(2)$ and use that $f(-h)=f(h).$

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Thank you for the start Fred, when i add them and apply the even property i get

2f'(0) = 2 limit (stuff) 

and if i subtract them i get 0=0

Comment: @Wombles: something went wrong. If you add them, then you will get $2f'(0)=0.$